# regex validation allow trailing space

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this regex pattern to validate a field with javascript.

```
\$[A-Z]*$
```

This validates a stock ticker symbol ex $GOOG or $AAPL

I would like to allow for trailing whitespace. So for example user hits space after the symbol, this would still be a valid symbol if possible.

Comment: Why don't you trim the string before using it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whitespace character `\s` should cover this nicely:

```
\$[A-Z]*\s*$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can then use this regex:

```
/\$[A-Z]+ *$/i
```

`[A-Z]+ *` will allow 0 or more spaces after alphabets.

Comment: The OP only wanted trailing whitespaces, I don't think he wants a case insensitive search... (and he may even want a hit with `$` alone). Just saying...

Comment: Sure in that case `/\$[A-Z]* *$/` might serve the OP. I just suggested some improvement on my own

Comment: and that was great, but you probably should explain it to him or at least point it out.